# how to check the client-side console logs to terminal or server side in nuxt 2.12

Tags: vue.js, logging, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there any built-in function that can provide the logs on the server side or terminal in nuxt 2.12?

I know asyncdata method does that but it will not provide the run time logs such as logs in created or any other methods.

I tried adding log4js and winston, consola npm packages but still, it is not giving me logs in the terminal.